# Dictionary ++ not working as expected

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-2.0

Let's say we have a dictionary like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
```

Whereas the key is the ID and the value is the count.
Now we want to add a new key. This works perfectly fine with the following line:

```
dic[1] = 1; //adding ID 1, Count 1 to the current Dictionary
```

Assuming we have a list of integer with the following values:

```
var ids = new List<int> {1, 2, 3 , 1, 2};
```

Where we would like to get a dictionary with the following content:

```
[1, 2] ==> (ID 1, Count 2)
[2, 2] ==> (ID 2, Count 2)
[3, 1] ==> (ID 3, Count 1)
```

The obvious solution would be:

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    dic[id]++;
}
```

But this is throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`. So obviously the operator `+=` is not supported for dictionaries.

I already attached an answer to this problem.
Is there any better way of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    if (dic.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        dic[id]++;
    } else {
        dic[id] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your `else` should contain `dic.Add(id, 1);`.

Comment: I stand corrected, [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx): _"You can also use the [indexer] property to add new elements by setting the value of a key that does not exist in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>."_

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for simpler:

```
var dic = ids.GroupBy(id => id)
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: I can't use LINQ. it's .NET 2.0. (Added tag now).
But I give you that this solution would be cleaner. ;)

Comment: @FabianBigler: how about [linqbridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to enable linq for .NET 2.0?

Comment: @CuongLe Thanks for the hint, I will have a look at it!